# sIFR onReplacement example

Tags: sifr

Can someone show me the proper way to invoke the onReplacement callback within sIFR.replace?

Here's my current sIFR.replace method call:

```
sIFR.replace(mainNavFont, {
  selector: 'a.nav-item',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #ffffff; cursor:pointer;}',
  wmode:'transparent',
  fitExactly: true,
  tuneWidth:10,
  offsetLeft: 5,
  forceSingleLine: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
sIFR.replace(mainNavFont, {
  selector: 'a.nav-item',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #ffffff; cursor:pointer;}',
  wmode:'transparent',
  fitExactly: true,
  tuneWidth:10,
  offsetLeft: 5,
  forceSingleLine: true,
  onReplacement: function(fi) {
    // Movie has been replaced
  }
});
```

Also, you'll find that replacing the `<a>` directly will break the links in most browsers. You have to replace the parent element such that the link ends up inside the Flash movie.